# Spring Rest Docs error - "No content to map due to end-of-input"

Tags: spring-restdocs

I have a test case on the Get method with Spring Rest Docs. It runs fine. With the same fashion of code on the Post method as the following:

```
  Foo foo = new Foo(...);
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/foos")
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(foo)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(header().string("Location", notNullValue()))
            .andDo(document("foo-post", preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()),
                    links(
                            halLinks(),
                            linkWithRel("self").description("..."),
                            linkWithRel("foo").description("...")),
                    responseFields(
                            fieldWithPath("attr1").description("..."),
                            fieldWithPath("attr2").description("..."),
                            ...
                            fieldWithPath("_links").description("<<resource-book-links,links>> to other resources")
                    )
            ));
```

I get an error, however.

```
org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.ModelCreationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: [B@47fca3cc; line: 1, column: 0]
at org.springframework.restdocs.hypermedia.LinksSnippet.createModel(LinksSnippet.java:131)
at org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet.document(TemplatedSnippet.java:64)
at org.springframework.restdocs.generate.RestDocumentationGenerator.handle(RestDocumentationGenerator.java:196)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationResultHandler.handle(RestDocumentationResultHandler.java:55)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andDo(MockMvc.java:177)
at com.example.SpringDataSampleApplicationTests.createBookRest(SpringDataSampleApplicationTests.java:173)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.restdocs.JUnitRestDocumentation$1.evaluate(JUnitRestDocumentation.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: [B@47fca3cc; line: 1, column: 0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3838)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3783)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2929)
at org.springframework.restdocs.hypermedia.AbstractJsonLinkExtractor.extractLinks(AbstractJsonLinkExtractor.java:41)
at org.springframework.restdocs.hypermedia.LinksSnippet.createModel(LinksSnippet.java:127)
... 41 more
```

If I comment out anything after "andDo(..)", it is fine. That means the problem is in the document section.

What is missing?

Comment: It looks like the response has no body. What's the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Hi Andy, I add the full stack trace in the question. If I comment on the responseFields section, the error also occurs. Also, the Post method has the same data for a Post as for Get.

Comment: It's the links snippet that's failing due to an empty response body. Given that you're testing for a 201 Created response with a Location header, an empty body would seem quite likely to me. Are you sure it's not empty?

Comment: Those tests are against Rest APIs created by Spring Data Rest. I double check the responses for both Get And Post methods. They are the same in terms of data  format. None of them is empty.

Comment: Have you customised Spring Data REST? By default, it won't return a body on a create without an appropriate accept header in the request. You need to either send an Accept header or call http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.html#setReturnBodyOnCreate-java.lang.Boolean-

Comment: When I said "I double check the responses", I mean I had sent requests to the Rest APIs. I did so by using Postman. I test them manually on Postman with a content-type setting on the header.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what else to suggest then. Perhaps you can share a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve) of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests using `MockMvc` are not setting an `Accept` header in the `POST` request. That means that, by default, Spring Data REST does not include a body in its 201 Created response. You either need to [configure Spring Data REST to always return a body for create requests](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.html#setReturnBodyOnCreate-java.lang.Boolean-) or you need to change your tests to send an `Accept` header.

Comment: Does the setting differ from a setting with Postman? In a manual test on Postman, an only thing I need to set in the header is content-type.  Also, I have a look at your test code https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/master/samples/rest-notes-spring-hateoas/src/test/java/com/example/notes/ApiDocumentation.java , I fail to see any difference in the header setting.

Comment: Those tests are using Spring HATEOAS, not Spring Data REST. They also do not document the body of a 201 response as there isn't one. Why not just try what I've suggested?

Comment: Interesting! It indeed works after I add accept with HAL JSON.

Comment: Thanks! This stumped me for a day.